# Prime N | Negative numbers don't work

Tags: python, math, numbers

I've writed this code for to tell if a number is prime (Y) or not (N).

```
number = int(input("Type a value for n. "))

if number > 1:
    for i in range(2, number):
        if (number % i)==0:
            print("N")
            break
    else:
        print("Y")
else:
    for i in range (number, -2):
        if ((number) % i)==0:
            print("N")
        break
    else:
        print("Y")
```

And it is working. But when i put a number less than 1 ( number < 1), like -7, the code give me an wrong answer.

I already made some changes and realized that :

```
number = int(input("Type a value for n. "))


if number > 1:
    for i in range(2, number):
        if (number % i)==0:
            print("N")
            break
    else:
        print("Y")
else:   
    for i in range (number,-2):
        if (number % i)==0:
            print("N")
            break

    else:
        print("Y")*
```

**But when I put: -7, the answer is N (wrong). -7 is a prime number**

Can someone help me ?

Comment: By what definition of *prime number" is -7 considered one?

Comment: @ScottHunter: It's a [prime element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) of the ring of (rational) integers, and it has the key property that whenever it divides the product of a finite collection of integers, it must divide one of those numbers. Not quite the same exact thing as "prime number", but it's a meaningful generalization. Similarly, if you want to define primes in the ring of Gaussian integers, the most natural definition is invariant under multiplication by `-1` or `i`. (I'd argue that `0` should also be considered a prime element, but I'm in a minority there.)

Answer (score 1):

it's because ranges/intervals in python are partially closed; they are open on the right.  So when you do

```
[i for i in range(2,10)]
```

you get

> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

notice, 2 is there, but 10 isn't

similarly

```
[i for i in range(-10,-2)]
```

will include -10, (thus number%i ==0 will be true) but not -2

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `abs`, absolute value function. It makes negatives positive and positives positive.

```
number = abs(int(input("Type a value for n. ")))

if number > 1:
    for i in range(2, number):
        if (number % i)==0:
            print("N")
            break
    else:
        print("Y")
else:
    for i in range (number, -2):
        if ((number) % i)==0:
            print("N")
        break
    else:
        print("Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

All prime numbers are natural numbers, that is to say, integers greater than 0.  Therefore, no negative number is prime.

Some sources:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219043027/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55940.html)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Comment: It's not so black and white. See https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/negative_primes.html and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1649531/117283 for example.